# Incrementing year on a specific date

Tags: ruby, date, conditional-statements

In my rails app a `user` can `subscribe` to a `tournament`, but before I need to check that my user has the right age to subscribe (ie that he is in the right category... a `tournament has_one category`). So I am writing something like :

```
elsif @tournament.category == "11 ans" && current_user.birthdate.year < 2004
```

I don’t like the fact that 2004 is written like this in my code. I d like to writte something more dynamic.
The way categories work is a bit complicated: A category is based on a sports season that goes from 1st of October to 30th September of the next year. 
So for example on 30th September 2015 we will pass from 2015 sports season to 2016 sports season. According to this the good way to writte my condition for the 11 year old category would be to writte something like this

```
elsif @tournament.category == "11 ans" && current_user.birthdate.year < YEAR – 11
```

where YEAR is the current sport year. Thus what I need is a way to make YEAR fit with the logic of the “sports calendar”. Any idea of a good way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compute the bounds for applying for that tournament when it's created? For example, "must be born between January 1st 2000 and Dec 31st 2001 for the 13-15 league" would translate to those two dates.

Expressed as a range:

```
age_limit = (tournament.birthdate_min..tournament.birthdate_max)
```

Using this to test:

```
age_limit.include?(current_user.birthdate)
```

For no upper limit on age, use a minimum date set in something like 1900.

Storing the description as `"11 ans"` and then hard-coding tests against that is going to get you into trouble. This is highly language specific, plus any change in formatting could trash your code. Use a simple coding method if you must, or leave the description as simply cosmetic, with the math part expressed as fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would shift the contestants age, not the tournament's.  So either increment `current_user.birthdate.year` when month is greater than 9 or decrement it when it is less than 10, depending on which one you consider to be 11 when the tournament occurs.

```
age = current_user.birthdate.month > 10 ? current_user.birthdate.year + 1 : current_user.birthdate.year
```